# Need to addlocal repo authorization to existing yaml file

Tags: yaml, authorization

I'm trying to deploy an nginx proxy in an airgapped environment. I've set up the local repo and it works with following setup below.

repo setup

- registry - localhost:5000
- user - jimmy
- password - neutron

I check the repo and it works.

```bash
[/tmp]$ curl -X GET -u jimmy:neutron https://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog

{"repositories":["ingress-nginx/controller","ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen"]}
```

Then I create a namespace and secret (the secret name and namespace i pulled from the yaml file)

```bash
kubectl create namespace ingress-nginx

kubectl create secret docker-registry ingress-nginx-admission \
--docker-server='https://localhost:5000' \
--docker-username='jimmy' \
--docker-password='neutron' \
--namespace=ingress-nginx
```

normally, I run when I have internet connection

```bash
kubectl apply -f  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.5.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

Here's the original deploy.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  name: ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
automountServiceAccountToken: true
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  - pods
  - secrets
  - endpoints
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - services
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingresses/status
  verbs:
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingressclasses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resourceNames:
  - ingress-nginx-leader
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - get
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - create
- apiGroups:
  - coordination.k8s.io
  resourceNames:
  - ingress-nginx-leader
  resources:
  - leases
  verbs:
  - get
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - coordination.k8s.io
  resources:
  - leases
  verbs:
  - create
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - create
  - patch
- apiGroups:
  - discovery.k8s.io
  resources:
  - endpointslices
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - get
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - secrets
  verbs:
  - get
  - create
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  - endpoints
  - nodes
  - pods
  - secrets
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - coordination.k8s.io
  resources:
  - leases
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - services
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - create
  - patch
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingresses/status
  verbs:
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingressclasses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - discovery.k8s.io
  resources:
  - endpointslices
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - get
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - admissionregistration.k8s.io
  resources:
  - validatingwebhookconfigurations
  verbs:
  - get
  - update
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: ingress-nginx
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ingress-nginx
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  allow-snippet-annotations: "true"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - appProtocol: http
    name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - appProtocol: https
    name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx-controller-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - appProtocol: https
    name: https-webhook
    port: 443
    targetPort: webhook
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  minReadySeconds: 0
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
        - --election-id=ingress-nginx-leader
        - --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx
        - --ingress-class=nginx
        - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
        - --validating-webhook=:8443
        - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
        - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: LD_PRELOAD
          value: /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
          image: localhost:5000/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.5.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command:
              - /wait-shutdown
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 5
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: controller
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 443
          name: https
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8443
          name: webhook
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 90Mi
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          capabilities:
            add:
            - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            drop:
            - ALL
          runAsUser: 101
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
          name: webhook-cert
          readOnly: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      volumes:
      - name: webhook-cert
        secret:
          secretName: ingress-nginx-admission
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx-admission-create
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
      name: ingress-nginx-admission-create
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - create
        - --host=ingress-nginx-controller-admission,ingress-nginx-controller-admission.$(POD_NAMESPACE).svc
        - --namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)
        - --secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission
        env:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          image: localhost:5000/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20220916-gd32f8c343
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: create
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 2000
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 2000
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx-admission
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx-admission-patch
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
      name: ingress-nginx-admission-patch
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - patch
        - --webhook-name=ingress-nginx-admission
        - --namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)
        - --patch-mutating=false
        - --secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission
        - --patch-failure-policy=Fail
        env:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          image: localhost:5000/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20220916-gd32f8c343
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: patch
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 2000
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 2000
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx-admission
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: nginx
spec:
  controller: k8s.io/ingress-nginx
---
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
webhooks:
- admissionReviewVersions:
  - v1
  clientConfig:
    service:
      name: ingress-nginx-controller-admission
      namespace: ingress-nginx
      path: /networking/v1/ingresses
  failurePolicy: Fail
  matchPolicy: Equivalent
  name: validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
  rules:
  - apiGroups:
    - networking.k8s.io
    apiVersions:
    - v1
    operations:
    - CREATE
    - UPDATE
    resources:
    - ingresses
  sideEffects: None
```

I just replace the registry values in the file. here's a diff the chabnges

```bash
<         image: localhost:5000/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.5.1@sha256:4ba73c697770664c1e00e9f968de14e08f606ff961c76e5d7033a4a9c593c629
---
>         image: registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.5.1@sha256:4ba73c697770664c1e00e9f968de14e08f606ff961c76e5d7033a4a9c593c629
551c551
<         image: localhost:5000/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20220916-gd32f8c343@sha256:39c5b2e3310dc4264d638ad28d9d1d96c4cbb2b2dcfb52368fe4e3c63f61e10f
---
>         image: registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20220916-gd32f8c343@sha256:39c5b2e3310dc4264d638ad28d9d1d96c4cbb2b2dcfb52368fe4e3c63f61e10f
600c600
<         image: localhost:5000/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20220916-gd32f8c343@sha256:39c5b2e3310dc4264d638ad28d9d1d96c4cbb2b2dcfb52368fe4e3c63f61e10f
---
>         image: registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v20220916-gd32f8c343@sha256:39c5b2e3310dc4264d638ad28d9d1d96c4cbb2b2dcfb52368fe4e3c63f61e10f
```

when run the kubectl apply, I get the following warning:

```bash
Warning: resource namespaces/ingress-nginx is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
```

then I get the errImgPulls

```bash
NAMESPACE       NAME                                            READY   STATUS         RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system     local-path-provisioner-6c86858495-tl64v         1/1     Running        0          3m7s
kube-system     coredns-6799fbcd5-t46vv                         1/1     Running        0          3m7s
kube-system     metrics-server-67c658944b-wfnx7                 1/1     Running        0          3m7s
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-admission-create-ntxhm            0/1     ErrImagePull   0          5s
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller-6d64b74d-tbsfr         0/1     ErrImagePull   0          5s
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-admission-patch-jstb8             0/1     ErrImagePull   0          5s
kube-system     svclb-ingress-nginx-controller-4ef00c0c-gr2b9   2/2     Running        0          5s
```

And when I look at /var/log/messages, I see the auth issues.

```bash
Mar 22 17:50:36 airgap k3s[15938]: E0322 17:50:36.680962   15938 kuberuntime_image.go:53] 

"Failed to pull image" err="failed to pull and unpack image \
"localhost:5000/ingress-nginx/controller@sha256:4ba73c697770664c1e00e9f968de14e08f606ff961c76e5d7033a4a9c593c629\": 

failed to resolve reference \"localhost:5000/ingress-nginx/controller@sha256:4ba73c697770664c1e00e9f968de14e08f606ff961c76e5d7033a4a9c593c629\": 
pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: 

authorization failed: no basic auth credentials" image="localhost:5000/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.5.1@sha256:4ba73c697770664c1e00e9f968de14e08f606ff961c76e5d7033a4a9c593c629"
```

I suspect it's a quick fix, but I'm stuck now.  any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

I tried to deploy nginx ingress controller in an airgapped environment, and I'm having basic authentication issues going on.